# Making pivot use index from underlying table of view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

My underlying table looks like this:

```
   ----------------------------
   | Id | Type  |Value      |
   ----------------------------
   | 1  |Name   |Michael    |
   | 1  |Age    |20         |
   | 2  |Name   |John       |
   | 3  |Name   |Smith      |
   | 5  |Age    |25         |
   ----------------------------
```

I have created an index on the column 'Type','Value'. (Edit: Added Value based on comments)

I explored a couple of options to give me a pivoted view. Something like this:

```
   ------------------------
   | Id |Name   |Age      |
   ------------------------
   | 1  |Michael|20       |
   | 2  |John   |         |
   | 3  |Smith  |25       |
   ------------------------
```

**Sql1 (Using pivot):**

```
CREATE View vw AS 
SELECT  
    ID
    NAME,
    AGE
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       ID,
       TYPE,
       VALUE
    FROM table
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(VALUE)
     FOR TYPE IN ([Name],[Age])
) piv
```

**Sql2 (Conditional aggregate)**

```
CREATE View vw AS 
SELECT
   Id,
   [Name]= MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE]='Name' THEN VALUE END),
   [Age] = MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE]='Age' THEN VALUE END)
FROM
   table
GROUP BY
   Id
```

When I run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM vw WHERE vw.Name = 'Michael'
```

I see that the execution plan is using index scans on the primary key (id). 
Is there any way to make this work so that it uses the index I created on 'Type' column?

Edit:
The reason why I don't have a flat table itself is because for each id, I might end up with around 100 fields. And it should be possible to do a search based on any of the field. So I was hoping a design like this may help if I was able to get the system to use the index on (Type, Value)

Comment: in your example ID is not primary key as IDs are duplicated. Also Sql1 query doesn't produce same results. And what kind of index you build for Type?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. My primary key is (ID, Type) combination. As for the other index on Type, it is a Non-Clustered Index.

Comment: Since you do not have any filter conditions, why do you expect an index to be used at all? Clustered index scan is what you need and what you get.

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean by not having any filter conditions. My filter condition is for the new Pivot column (WHERE vw.Name = 'Michael').

Based on above comment, I added a nonclustered index for (Type, Value). I am expecting it to be used instead of the primary key scan when I add the clause, WHERE vw.Name = 'Michael'

Comment: try to create index on view, not on table

Comment: @Noel, 1. SQL Server cannot use indexes when a column is wrapped in a function (especially aggregate functions). You expect/hope that SQL Server will do a "inverse pivot" when you specify filters to your view to figure out what columns/values you are actually after. 2. "I might end up with around 100 fields" - table with 100 fields is much better than a dynamically pivoted view with 100 fields. My recommendation is to create a table with all "mandatory" fields as columns e.g. name, age etc. and have another table with "optional" fields in the same format as your current table.

Comment: @Alex, thanks. I think you confirmed my fears. 
If I want the ability to search on any of the columns (mandatory or optional), would it make sense then to add indexes to each column? Or would it be better to create the index on the view itself. I am guessing both the approaches would have the same performance impact on inserts/updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SEEK, you can improve your code:

```
SELECT * FROM vw WHERE vw.Name = 'Michael'
```

to replace Name with ID (or add ID filter) in WHERE condition

```
SELECT * FROM vw WHERE vw.Name = 'Michael' and ID = 1
```

or just

```
SELECT * FROM vw WHERE ID = 1
```

If you don't have that ID value during execution time, you can get it before that query or use subquery / join. You may need to create an index for Type and Value in order to find quickly that ID.

Comment: I don't know how that is going to help if I want to find the records where Name = 'Michael'. If I get the id, then I don't need to run this query. 
Another thing is that I could design the underlying table itself to look like the view. But I am expecting the table to have around 100 columns and the data should be searchable on any of it. Adding an index per column would slow down inserts and updates significantly.

Comment: 100 columns of what? You mean Type1 Value1 Type2 Value 2... Type100 Value100?  If you're going just to have 100 values/100 types (so you still have only ID/Value/Type columns), that's covered by this answer.

Comment: I mean my table could be designed two ways
Id, Type, Value 
or 
Id, Name, Age, AddressCity, AddressState....Salary (100 records)

The first approach would mean 100 records per 1 id.
The second approach would mean 1 record per id. 

I could want to search based on Name or Age or Salary or City etc.

Comment: What I meant is that if you decide to implement the first approach, my method would work. The subquery will find all IDs with searched strings, and then it will use index seek if query optimizer thinks index seek is better (when not too many IDs with same searched strings). If a table is huge you can also add partitioning by [Type], so when you search for particular type, it will look into only one partition, other partitions will be eliminated